# Replacing a specific character in a string

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

This may be very basic, but I've been struggling with it.

I have something like:

`one = ['L', 'K', 'M']`

`two = ['P', 'N', 'S']`

I also have a string, let's say it's something like "LooK at Me", which I want to transform into "PooN at Se". My idea is to loop though each letter of the string, and loop though the first list, compare the two, and if they're a match, to simply replace the letter in the string that is a match with something from the list one with it's pair from list two.

The looping proves to be very inefficient, as I am working with large texts.

The string I am accessing are in fact rows in a pandas dataframe:

`data = pd.read_csv('train.txt', delimiter='\t', header=None, names=['category', 'text'], dtype=str)`

and `print data.head()` gives something like:

`0  MUSIC  Today at the recording studio, John...
1  POLITICS  The tensions inside the government have...
2  NEWS  The new pictures of NASA show...`

I separate the texts like

`text = data['text']`

The trick here is, I am actually working with text written in Cyrillic, and I can't use any of the functions to lower the upper case letters, which is my goal. The best I've up with is the problem I introduced at the top, to simply locate each upper case letter and replace it with it's lower case equivalent.

Any words of advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
print (data)
                                                text
0         MUSIC  Today at the recording studio, John
1  POLITICS  The tensions inside the government have
2                NEWS  The new pictures of NASA show

one = ['L', 'K', 'M']
two = ['P', 'N', 'S']
data['text'] = data['text'].replace(one, two, regex=True)
print (data)
                                                text
0         SUSIC  Today at the recording studio, John
1  POPITICS  The tensions inside the government have
2                NEWS  The new pictures of NASA show
```

Comment: A follow up, now to remove all the symbols 

`symbols = ['!', '„', '“', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '?', '+', '=', '.', ',']`

I tried:


`data['text'] = data['text'].replace(symbols, "", regex=True)`

But it didn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need escape some chars, because interpreted as regex `symbols = ['!', '„', '“', '$', '%', '^', '&', '\*', '\(', '\)', '-', '\?', '\+', '=', '\.', ',']`

Answer (score 1):

```
#use list comprehension
''.join([e if e not in one else two[one.index(e)] for i,e in enumerate(s)])
Out[523]: 'PooN at Se'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a translation table, and use the `translate` method.

```
translation_table = str.maketrans("ABÉПЯ", "abéпя")

text = "Éléphant Язы́к"

text.translate(translation_table)
# 'éléphant язы́к'
```

We use [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to create the translation table. We use it with to parameters, two strings of equal length.
Then we use the [translate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method of our string.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use vectorized [.str.translate()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.translate.html) method, which is designed for such things:

```
In [62]: one = ['S','o','a']

In [63]: two = ['$', '0', '@']

In [64]: tran_tab = str.maketrans(''.join(one), ''.join(two))

In [65]: data.text.str.translate(tran_tab)
Out[65]:
0           MU$IC  T0d@y @t the rec0rding studi0, J0hn
1    POLITIC$  The tensi0ns inside the g0vernment h@ve
2                  NEW$  The new pictures 0f NA$A sh0w
Name: text, dtype: object
```